# TortoiseGit - Is possible to set a colour to a branch?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

In the log messages representation, in the graph displayed in the left side is represented the commits, merges, etc.

Can I set for example the black line always to my master branch?
In my example master is the red line.... and I would like it to be ALWAYS black line or the first one.... is there any option, script to edit, etc, where I can do it?

Thanks in advance!

[image: My example]

Comment: in the TGit options (Colors3) you can only configure the colors based on the number. here the 1st is black, the 2nd red and the 3rd green. Ask this the TGit developers: https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues

Comment: Thank you! I just added an issue at their gitlab... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such option (and is nothing planned: https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/2589)

All you can do is the change the color for the current branch, *all* local or remote branches or *all* tags in TortoiseGit settings.

Comment: But the issue is officially commented.

Comment: Yep, sorry I completely forgot this issue. My Apologizes